# Using s3cmd from AWS Ec2 to AWS S3 container failing with Connection Error: Error resolving a server hostname

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3cmd

I have a Amazon Aws EC2 instance, and sometimes I upload files to my Amazon AWS S3 container. It usually works fine but now failing as below

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-36-94:~/code/indexes$ s3cmd put artist_index.tar.gz s3://jthink/artist_index_21.tar.gz
ERROR: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
ERROR: Connection Error: Error resolving a server hostname.
Please check the servers address specified in 'host_base', 'host_bucket', 'cloudfront_host', 'website_endpoint'
```

Waited a few hours and still failing in same way

The only thing I have changed on the server since it last worked is I increased the size of the main volume, grow the partition to match and reboot EC2 instance, doesn't seem that is relevant to problem.

Since I have been waiting for a few hours and AWS is usually very reliable I don't know if this *Temporary Failure* really is temporary or not ?

**Update**
Tried it again today and it still failed, rebooted and now working. So perhaps it was just a temporary problem, but why would I need to reboot.

Comment: **Side-note:** These days, it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`, which is [rarely updated](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/releases).